# Удалённый запуск скрипта на Python через ssh без ключей

Tags: python, bash, ssh

Есть необходимость чтоб скрипт на сервере (А) запускал скрип на сервере (В)   и получал ответ отработки от (В).

Раньше я смотрел в сторону поднятия на обоих машинах Sokect (Server-client)

Но ведь можно же достучаться из (А) примерно как-то так:

```
ssh://root@B.B.B.B/usr/bin/python3.4/python/usr/local/work
```

1. Есть ли какая нибудь библиотека типа sh, bash или это всё умеет os, sys?
2. Далее нужно туда передать ещё пароль, это смотреть в man ssh?
3. Без использования доступа по ключам.

Comment: А поиск использовать не пробовали? Он бы подсказал несколько библиотек для этого: [первая](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh/1.7.13), [вторая](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko), [третья](http://python-for-system-administrators.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ssh.html), продолжать?

Comment: @BOPOH: Stack Overflow это как раз и есть место куда поисковики направляют. Поэтому, до тех пор пока нет вопроса-дубликата, этот вопрос уместен здесь (если его разбить на несколько).

Comment: @jfs, т.е. вы поддерживаете вопросы, в которых автор ничего не сделал для получения ответа на свой вопрос ("Есть ли какая нибудь библиотека")? Если так продолжать дальше, то даже поиском по сайту пользоваться не будут. Или вам нравится находить дубликаты за авторов и закрывать вопросы? Специально для вас могу создать полностью дублирующие вопросы старого ХК. И во-вторых - с каких пор советы типа "какая библиотека лучше" стали приемлемыми? `Вопросы с просьбами предоставить рекомендации или найти... библиотеки... являются на Stack Overflow вопросами не по теме`

Comment: @BOPOH : не стоит вести себя в манере "а я назло папе уши отморожу". Если я пришёл из гугла с тем же вопросом, то мне не поможет приложил ли автор какие-либо усилия или нет, меня интересует только рабочий пример кода с `paramiko` (или другое решение, например, с `pexpect`).  Этот вопрос не относится к типу "какая библиотека лучше" -- как поменяются ответы, если убрать целиком первый пункт из вопроса?

Comment: @jfs, если убрать первый пункт, вопрос не изменится, т.к. не указано что использует автор, а значит вариантов на основе различных библиотек будет куча. К тому же, если изменить вопрос, то он может уже соответствовать требованию к вопросам. Любой плохой вопрос можно сделать "хорошим" изменив его, поэтому такая возможность не делает вопрос "хорошим" без фактического его изменения. И если вас интересует работа с `pexpect`, а в ответах приведен `paramiko`, то это никоим образом вам не поможет.

Comment: @BOPOH: не нужно лезть в бутылку -- всё как раз с точностью до наоборот: если вопрос явно не указывает ограничения (такие как: нельзя установить дополнительные модули или указана ОСь, на которой не доступны определённые модули), то можно использовать всё что автор ответа сочтёт нужным.

Comment: @jfs, я отвечал на ваше "я пришел с гугла посмотреть на paramiko". А ваш последний коммент как раз и указывает возможную причину закрытия вопроса: всеобъемлющий (`На этот вопрос можно дать слишком много ответов... Пожалуйста, уточните подробности, чтобы сократить количество ответов...`). Хотя я больше склоняюсь к варианту "вопрос с просьбой дать рекомендации". Если бы автор не поленился воспользоваться поиском, взял бы первую попавшуюся библиотеку и уже в ней не смог передать пароль - было бы совсем другое дело. ЗЫ: дальнейшее обсуждение (если оно требуется) стоит вести в отдельном чате.

Comment: Вы может это в чате/мете обсудите? Ваши комментарии к вопросу вообще отношения не имеют

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, `ssh` не имеет способа принять пароль через параметр командной строки, поэтому без использования дополнительных средств не обойтись.

Для Python существует библиотека [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/), позволяющая работать с SSH.

Выглядеть это будет таким образом:

```
import paramiko

server_auth = {
    'hostname': '<hostname>',
    'username': '<username>', 
    'password': '<password>', 
    'port': <port>
}

with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.connect(**server_auth)
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python script.py')

    print(stdout.read().decode())  # читать нужно, пока открыт ssh
```

При этом `stdin`, `stdout` и `stderr` ведут себя, как файлы. Если вам требуется что-то передать на стандартный вход программе, пишите в `stdin`; если требуется что-то получить от скрипта, читайте из `stdout`; если хотите контролировать поток ошибок программы, используйте `stderr`.

---

Дополнительные ссылки:

- [Пример работы с библиотекой](http://olezhek.net/2010-07-06-zametki-o-python-rabotaem-s-ssh.html)
- [Статья на хабре про библиотеку](http://habrahabr.ru/post/150047/) (в комментариях описаны ссылки на дополнительные способы решения задачи)
- [Документация по paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/)

Answer (score 3):

самый простой способ - копируем скрипт на удаленный сервер (это можно сделать как ручками, так и с помощью scp). А потом просто выполняем команду вида `ssh user@server 'python script.py'`. Ответ будет выдан в STDOUT, поэтому его легко получить (точно также, как от любой другой программы, которая запускается локально).

Если скрипт генерируется ручками каждый раз и копировать лень (бывает), то выполняем например так `cat script | ssh user@server 'python'`. В случае с перлом, нужно писать ещё минус, что бы он понимал, что файл пришел с пайпа (`perl -`).

И последнее - пароль. Если скрипт должен выполнятся без участия пользователя - настройте ssh логин по ключу. Это самый правильный и простой способ. Как настроить [доступ по ключам](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2).

Comment: нет скрипт уже там  , его надо запускать с скрипта на другом сервере

Comment: тогда никаких проблем не вижу.

Comment: я не хочу использовать доступ по ключам

Comment: Тогда придется научиться запускать ssh под псевдотерминалом (pty) и передавать ему пароль.

Comment: @xmaster83 старайтесь сразу указывать все ограничения в вопросе

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая утилита - [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/). Дает возможность передавать пароль параметром командной строки.

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
sshpass -p 'mypassword' ssh username@server.example.com
```

Но как уже говорилось - правильный способ, это доступ по ssh ключу.